# When opening encrypted mails with Kontact/Kmail the subject is not decrypted

Tags: encryption, email, openpgp, kmail, kontact

When I receive emails with Kontact/Kmail that are encrypted with OpenPGP I am not able to get its subject.

When I open then and provide the proper password the *body* gets decrypted fine, but the *subject* still shows as `…`.

How can I find out what the sender has entered as subject?